# What happens if I use a font that isn't installed on the client machine?

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010, fonts

Can someone tell me what happens if I use a font in my WinForms app that isn't available on the target machine? Does it use a font in the same family, just Sans Serif, or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your application will fallback to Segoe UI, Tahoma, then MS Sans Serif depending on the OS Version.